# JavaScript - selenium-webdriver - can't find a scroll method

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

On the page https://www.ameublement.com/showroom, I go to each brand but after 5-7 brands, the script can't go further because it needs to scroll the page. This is the error:

> ElementClickInterceptedError: element click intercepted: Element  is not clickable at point (389, 539). Other element would receive the click: <span ...

This is my code:

```
let swd = require("selenium-webdriver");
let browser = new swd.Builder();
let tab = browser.setChromeOptions().forBrowser("chrome").build();

async function main() {

    await tab.get("https://www.ameublement.com/showroom");

    // PAGE BRAND
    let brands = await tab.findElements(
        swd.By.css(".col-6.col-lg-12.card-img")
    );

    for (let e of brands) {
        console.log('go to page of a brand')
        await e.click()

        tab.sleep(300);

        // GO BACK
        tab.navigate().back()

        // await tab.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", e);
        // tab.getElementByClassName(e).scrollIntoView();

    };
}
```

I tried:

```
// await tab.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", e);
```

then I tried:

```
// tab.getElementByClassName(e).scrollIntoView();
```

The second one throw this error:

> TypeError: tab.getElementByClassName is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `tab` is an instance of [ThenableWebDriver](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_ThenableWebDriver.html) which has no such function. Please see the link for documentation.

What you could do instead is use simple javascript to scroll, e.g.

`await tab.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,1000)");`